# How to pull users from database and list them in a table view using firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm using firebase to make an iOS app. I want to retrieve all the users on my database and display their name and profile picture in a table view. Here is my code for my `TableViewCell`:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import SDWebImage

class HomeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var messageImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var likeCountButton: UIButton!

    var homeVC: HomeViewController?
    var postReference: DatabaseReference!

    var post: UserFile?{
        didSet {
            updateView()
        }
    }

    var user: UserFile? {
        didSet {
            updateUserInfo()
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        nameLabel.text = ""

        let berryTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLikeTap))

        likeImageView.addGestureRecognizer(berryTapGesture)
        likeImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func updateView() {
        if let photoURL = post?.picURL {
            profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: photoURL))
        }

        API.Post.REF_POSTS.child(post!.id!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { postSnapshot in
            if let postDictionary = postSnapshot.value as? [String:Any] {
                let post = UserFile.transformPost(postDictionary: postDictionary, key: postSnapshot.key)
                self.updateLike(post: post)
            }
        })
        API.Post.REF_POSTS.child(post!.id!).observe(.childChanged, with: { snapshot in
            if let value = snapshot.value as? Int {
                self.likeCountButton.setTitle("\(value) berries", for: .normal)
            }
        })
    }

    func updateLike(post: UserFile) {
        let imageName = post.berries == nil || !post.isBerried! ? "berry" : "berrySelected"
        likeImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

        // display a message for berries
        guard let count = post.berryCount else {
            return
        }

        if count != 0 {
            likeCountButton.setTitle("\(count) berries", for: .normal)
        } else if post.berryCount == 0 {
            likeCountButton.setTitle("Be the first to Like this", for: .normal)
        }
    }

    func incrementberries(forReference ref: DatabaseReference) {
        ref.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
            if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                var berries: Dictionary<String, Bool>
                berries = post["berries"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
                var likeCount = post["berryCount"] as? Int ?? 0
                if let _ = berries[uid] {
                    // Unlike the post and remove self from stars
                    likeCount -= 1
                    berries.removeValue(forKey: uid)
                } else {
                    // Like the post and add self to stars
                    likeCount += 1
                    berries[uid] = true
                }
                post["berryCount"] = likeCount as AnyObject?
                post["berries"] = berries as AnyObject?

                currentData.value = post

                return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
            }
            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            if let postDictionary = snapshot?.value as? [String:Any] {
                let post = UserFile.transformPost(postDictionary: postDictionary, key: snapshot!.key)
                self.updateLike(post: post)
            }
        }
    }

    func handleLikeTap() {
        postReference = API.Post.REF_POSTS.child(post!.id!)
        incrementberries(forReference: postReference)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: "industribune-default-no-profile-pic")
    }

    func updateUserInfo() {
        nameLabel.text = user?.username
        if let photoURL = user?.profileImageURL {
            profileImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: photoURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "industribune-default-no-profile-pic"))
        }
    }


}
```

I am displaying this cell on my `HomeViewController`:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import Firebase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var posts = [UserFile]()
    var users = [UserFile]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // for performance set an estimated row height
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 1
        // but also request to dynamically adjust to content using AutoLayout
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        //tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        loadPosts()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadPosts() {
        activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

        API.User.observePosts { (newPost) in
            guard let userID = newPost.uid else { return }
            self.fetchUser(uid: userID, completed: {
                // append the new Post and Reload after the user
                // has been cached
                self.posts.append(newPost)
                self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }

    func fetchUser(uid: String, completed: @escaping () -> Void) {

        API.User.observeUser(withID: uid) { user in
            self.users.append(user)

            completed()
        }
    }


}

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

        cell.post = posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.user = users[indexPath.row]
        cell.homeVC = self

        return cell
    }

}
```

I have a lot of craziness going on in my project so **let me know if you have any questions** and what I'm doing wrong. If it's too complicated to understand I'm ready to erase everything and start over too.

And I do honestly think that I followed all the guidelines to ask a question so don't like shut this question down or something.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of code. Try this super reduced example. For this, the users node only stores the name as a child node but it could also have an image, email, address, etc.

Example users node

```
users
  uid_0:
     name: "Bert"
  uid_1:
     name: "Ernie"
```

and some code

```
var usersArray = [ [String: Any] ]()  //an array of dictionaries.

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //set up firebase references here
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
        usersRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
         for child in snapshot.children {
              let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
              let userDict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
              self.usersArray.append(userDict)
         }
         self.tableView.reloadData()
   })
```

and the tableView delegate methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.usersArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

    let userDict = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.text = userDict["name"] as! String
    //cell.imge = userDict["image"] etc etc

    return cell
}
```

Now... that all being said. This is the perfect use for an array of UserClass objects instead of the dictionaries.

Here's a starting point....

```
class UserClass {
   var name = ""
   var image = ""

   func init(snap: DataSnapshot) {
     //populate the vars from the snapshot
   }
}

var userClassArray = [UserClass]()
```

Don't copy and paste this as there are probably typos but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: `let userDict = child.value as! [String: Any]` keeps giving me an error? I'm kinda a beginner at Swift so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @B.Pandey Whoops. Left out some code - it's been updated. The idea is to iterate over the child nodes returned in the snapshot one by one. Each iteration object (child) is an enumerator object. We cast that to a data snapshot (let snap = child as! DataSnapshot) so we can access it's value. That value is then cast to a dictionary to access the individual elements. This could be written with fewer lines of code but I left it verbose to make the concept clearer.

Comment: And the last few lines of code that begins with `class UserClass {` should I put that in a new Swift file or what? Like basically I'm asking where should I put those last few lines of code?

Comment: @B.Pandey As mentioned in the answer, instead of using dictionaries to work with your data, you could wrap them into a UserClass instead which would be much cleaner code. If you are comfortable [implementing classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html) in Swift, then it's the way to go. If not, stick with the dictionaries for now.

Comment: I have no idea why this answer is not the chosen one, and had 0 upvotes. +1: worked perfectly for me with almost no needed adjustments. TYVM!! I've been looking for this answer for nearly a week.